# Mask an image (np.ndarray) section which lies between two curves

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, mask, scikit-image

Borrowing this example from astropy:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.utils.data import download_file

fits_file = 'http://data.astropy.org/tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits'
image_file = download_file(fits_file, cache=True)
hdu = fits.open(image_file)[0]
wcs = WCS(hdu.header)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.imshow(hdu.data, origin='lower', cmap='cubehelix')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')

x_array = np.arange(0, 1000)
line_1 = 1 * x_array + 20 * np.sin(0.05*x_array)
line_2 = x_array - 100 + 20 * np.sin(0.05*x_array)

plt.plot(x_array, line_1, color='red')
plt.plot(x_array, line_2, color='red')

ax.set_xlim(0, hdu.shape[1])
ax.set_ylim(0, hdu.shape[0])

plt.show()
```

I would like to calculate the median pixel value (in y direction for example) which lies between the two curves:

[image]

I believe the clever thing would be to create a mask for the region of interest.

Is there a way to generate this mask without looping across the image pixels?

Edit 1: Modified question improve understanding

Edit 2: I changed the example to better represent the question title (curves instead of straight lines)

Comment: You'd like to calculate the median value of what, exactly? If you're trying to find the center of the area bounded by those two lines, isn't that just finding the midpoint of a trapezoid?

Comment: Sorry I wanted to say median pixel value  between those lines in the y direction.

Comment: So you could find the midpoint coordinates of that trapezoid and then index the image to find the RGB  value. Working on a solution now....

Comment: I do not think I follow you: The output should be an array not a single point... also in this case the lines are  parallel but it might not be the case...

Comment: Are you looking for the RGB for the middlemost point? Or the average RGB value for all pixels contained in that shape? Those are two different questions.

Comment: For example going from the bottom to the top of the image I want the median value for the pixels within those two curves for each row. (without looping) The image is not RGB composition is just a np.ndarray with a cmap.

Comment: I'm looking into solutions. In the meantime, if you haven't seen [this](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/usage/image.html), it might be valuable.

Comment: Thank you. I have adapted the initial example to make it more understandable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fairly straight forward way of generating such a mask would be to use the `numpy.mgrid` thingy that essentially gives you x and y-coordinate arrays (in that 2D case) that can then be used to compute the mask with the equation of the lines .

**Edit :** Provided you can express your mask using an equation (like `f(x,y)<0` where f is any function you want) or a combination of those equations, you can do anything you want. Here is an example with your new mask along with some extra art pieces:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y,x=np.mgrid[0:1000,0:1000]

#a wiggly ramp
plt.subplot(221)
mask0=(y < x + 20 * np.sin(0.05*x)) & (y > x - 100 + 20 * np.sin(0.05*x))
plt.imshow(mask0,origin='lower',cmap='gray')

#a ramp
plt.subplot(222)
mask1=(y < x) & (x < y+100)
plt.imshow(mask1,origin='lower',cmap='gray')

#a disk
plt.subplot(223)
mask2=(200**2>(x-500)**2+(y-500)**2)
plt.imshow(mask2,origin='lower',cmap='gray')

#a ying-yang attempt
plt.subplot(224)
mask3= (mask2 & (0 < np.sin(3.14*x/250)*100 + 500 - y) & (30**2 < (x-620)**2+(y-500)**2) )| (30**2 > (x-380)**2+(y-500)**2)
plt.imshow(mask3,origin='lower',cmap='gray')

plt.show()
```

Output :

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you very much @jadsq for your example. I was not aware of this mgrid method... However I did not provide a good example for my question: This solution will work for straight lines but not curves... I have changed my initial code to better represent the problem... do you think it can be adapted somehow?

Answer (score 5):

The code snippet below creates a mask, sets all values outside the mask to nan, and then uses NumPy's `nanmedian` to calculate the desired quantity along the direction indicated.

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

from skimage.measure import grid_points_in_poly


# Create test image
N = 900
image = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N * N).reshape((N, N)) ** 2)

# Define the mask polygon
poly = [[N, 0],
        [0, N],
        [100, N],
        [N, 100]]

# Create the mask (True is inside the polygon)
mask = grid_points_in_poly(image.shape, poly)

# Set everything outside the mask to nan
masked_image = image.copy()
masked_image[~mask] = np.nan

# Perform the required operation
row_med = np.nanmedian(masked_image, axis=1)

# The rest of the code is to visualize the result
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 3, width_ratios=(1, 1, 1/8))
ax0 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[2])

ax0.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
ax0.set_title('Input image')
ax0.set_xlim(0, N)

ax1.imshow(masked_image, cmap='gray')
ax1.set_title('Masked image')
ax1.set_xlim(0, N)

ax2.plot(row_med, np.arange(N))
ax2.set_ylim([N, 0])
ax2.set_xlim([-1.5, 1.5])
ax2.set_title('Row median')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Median along rows inside region of interest]

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply Stefan! It is a very clean, however I think I did not explain myself properly: I believe this polygon method will only work if the section edges are completely straight... It will not give the right solution for curved edges... Do you think it can be adapted somehow? (I have updated the example using a bit of yours)

Comment: In that case, the above two posted solutions in combination gives you what you need.  Not that you are consuming a lot of memory with this operation; a loop in Cython, numba, pypi, etc. would be much quicker.